# Lenses for Olympus OMD-EM10 Mark II

Tags: lens, olympus, micro-four-thirds

I have an *Olympus OMD-EM10 Mark II* with this lens: *M.Zuiko 14-42mm*. I got it 6 months ago and now I want to take more specific photos, like wide angle, little objects, time lapse and astrophotography.

So, what can you suggest? And why?

Comment: 14 mm *is* wide angle, unless this camera has a rather small sensor.  *"Time lapse"* doesn't specify a lens type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes I know but I want more if possible. And for astrophotography?

Comment: Hi! I also got one of these cameras recently. I happened to have plenty of old 35mm lenses at home; bought adapters and have been using them by now. you could consider of getting an adapter and buying old vintage lenses in order to try other focal lenghts and apertures before you finally invest in expensive modern lenses. regarding which adapter to get, you have two options: focus on old olympus lenses, which might maybe be more compatible with m43 than the others; or simply getting an adapter for a very old and popular mount, for which plenty of old lenses will be available (e.g. m42)

Comment: An interesting direction to follow regarding which adapter to buy could be getting a rangefinder mount 35mm adapter, which probably would allow you to better enjoy the compactness enabled by your m43 camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you feel your lens isn't wide enough you probably want a wide-angle zoom. There are also wide-angle primes, but a zoom gives you more compositional choices, which is especially important for landscape photography and astrophotography. As far as I can tell there are only four wide angle zooms available for the micro 4/3 ecosystem: the Olympus 9-18mm f4-5.6, the 7-14mm f2.8 pro (the latter is faster, which may be an important consideration for the astrophotography), the Panasonic 7-14mm F4 and the 8-18mm F2.8-4. As for the macro lens the Olympus 60mm f2.8 macro seems to have very good reviews, so that might be something you can check out.

---

**Disclamer**: I don't own any of the above lenses, so my advice is based on the limited information I could find on the Internet.

**My advice**
I would consider if you really need these, usually speciality lenses are more expensive then the general-purpose lenses, I would rent one and see if it is really necessary to buy it for your needs. Just to let you know, you could probably do astrophotography with the lens you already have, a lot of it is knowledge of camera settings and post-processing, although if you are really into that kind of photography you may get better results with a wider and faster lens. For the macro, there are tricks you can use to do macro photography with just about any old lens. As for the wide-angle you can stitch together a couple shots to emulate shooting with a very wide angle lens.

Comment: Three is also a Panasonic 7-14mm F4 and an 8-18mm F2.8-4 lens

Comment: Thank you for your answer which is really complete. I'm going to check for this two lens.

Comment: @pierreafranck as mentioned in the comment above there are also the panasonic 7-14mm f4 and 8-18 F2.8-4 lenses of which I was not aware when writing the post.